# How to get notification when a view controller pop or push in to the navigation controller stack

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, navigation, stack

I want to get notification when a view controller pop or push in the navigation controller stack.
I tried to use

```
- (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers
```

But I failed.
And I do not want to use delegate method to achieve this...

Comment: What object or objects, do you want to receive these notifications?

Answer (score 4):

You can subclass UINavigationController and override some methods:

```
- (NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"poped" object:nil userInfo:@{}];
    return [super popToRootViewControllerAnimated:animated];
}

- (NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"poped" object:nil userInfo:@{}];
    return [super popToViewController:viewController animated:animated];
}

- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"poped" object:nil userInfo:@{}];
    return [super popViewControllerAnimated:animated];
}

- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"pushed" object:nil userInfo:@{}];
    return [super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated];
}
```

i left user info like @{}, but you can place there something if You want, like controller that was added or removed.

I don't know, but I think You should think twice, if You architecture need notifications for such situation.

Also You have to check does pop methods call each other, in such situation you can get few notifications for one pop.

Comment: I first use this way to solve the problem,    -     (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated  Thanks all the same.

Comment: Posting a notification on behalf of `nil` is a bad practise in general. In this particular case you don't be able to distinguish if event happen in your navigation VC, or in another tab, or maybe in a modal one. Rule of thumb is to always post notification on behalf of a specific object, and always subscribe to notifications posted on behalf of a specific object.

Answer (score 4):

I use UINavigationControllerDelegate method to solve this problem.

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
      willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                    animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: Yes, it works nice, thanks. But I have an architecture question: what object do you assign as a navigationController.delegate? Root view controller?

Comment: Assign it to the navigation controller. Subclass the navigation controller, add the delegate to the subclass, and finally select the subclassed navigation controller in the dropdown for in the identity inspector of the navigation scene.